# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment (Error 450) Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform the populate a spreadsheet I have added code to the "enter" button.
I keep getting error 450, please advise. I have copied this format from a code I have used before with no errors. the only new thing is the if then statement in the first Sub.

```
    Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
    On Error Resume Next

    If cmbcash.Value = "yes" Then
    Sheets(Sheet1).[a1].Value = frmInput.txtCash
    Sheets(Sheet1).[a2].Value = frmInput.txtCash
    Else
    Sheets(Sheet1).[a2].Value = frmInput.txtcash2
    If cmbstock.Value = "yes" Then
    Sheets(Sheet1).[b1].Value = frmInput.txtstock
    Sheets(Sheet1).[b2].Value = frmInput.txtstock
    Else
    Sheets(Sheet1).[b2].Value = frmInput.txtstock2
    If cmbdeposits.Value = "yes" Then
    Sheets(Sheet1).[c1].Value = frmInput.txtdeposits
    Sheets(Sheet1).[c2].Value = frmInput.txtdeposits
    Else
    Sheets(Sheet1).[c2].Value = frmInput.txtdeposits2
    End If

    Hide Me



    End Sub






    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim x
Dim y

    y = Array("Transfer", "Don't Transfer", "Retirement at 75%")
    x = Array("Yes", "No")

    cmbcash.Value = " "
    cmbstock.Value = " "
    cmbdeposits.Value = " "

    cmbcash.List = x
    cmbstock.List = x
    cmbdeposits.List = x





    End Sub
```

Comment: Whar are `cmbcash`, `cmbstock` and `cmbdeposits`?

Comment: they are comboboxes with two available values, "yes" and "no"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `End If` for each `If`.  You should also almost certainly remove `On Error Resume Next` - fix your errors, don't ignore them or you will get unintended results!

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

    If cmbcash.Value = "yes" Then
        Sheets(Sheet1).[a1].Value = frmInput.txtCash
        Sheets(Sheet1).[a2].Value = frmInput.txtCash
    Else
        Sheets(Sheet1).[a2].Value = frmInput.txtcash2
    END if
    If cmbstock.Value = "yes" Then
        Sheets(Sheet1).[b1].Value = frmInput.txtstock
        Sheets(Sheet1).[b2].Value = frmInput.txtstock
    Else
        Sheets(Sheet1).[b2].Value = frmInput.txtstock2
    END if
    If cmbdeposits.Value = "yes" Then
        Sheets(Sheet1).[c1].Value = frmInput.txtdeposits
        Sheets(Sheet1).[c2].Value = frmInput.txtdeposits
    Else
        Sheets(Sheet1).[c2].Value = frmInput.txtdeposits2
    End If

    Hide Me

    End Sub
```

Comment: you were right dave thanks. I am now having another problem. the program is doing the else function even though I am selecting yes on the combobox. to illustrate: c1 is being populated correctly but c2 is blank. when I remove the "2" from the txtcash, it populates both cells.